# How to detect assignment to a mis-cased instance variable in Python

Tags: python, variables, declaration, detection, case-sensitive

I just ran into a somewhat hard to detect issue in Python. We're using the xml module (xml.etree.ElementTree.Element), where you have elements and the elements have a "text" instance variable. But someone used "Text" (note, uppercase "T"). The generated XML of course did not contain the expected string.

This didn't throw any errors or anything, other than the program just not working properly, and I think I understand why.

My question is, **is there a good way to detect this problem?** I feel like if there were I'd probably find a few similar mistakes if I were able to scan all of our files.

I've tried pylint and pyflakes but neither tool seems to detect this.

I remember in some other language there was an option you could set to require explicit declaration before usage (it's funny, I forget which language that was now, Ada maybe?), and I know declaration isn't very Pythonic, but it would seem adding "names" to an instance of a class shouldn't be very standard usage either.

Comment: Perl has `use strict;` and `use warnings;` that provide cross-checks, and would warn about a variable that's used just once.

Comment: This seems more like a question about XML validation than it does about Python variables. You could use some sort of XML schema validator to verify that the output your code generates is correct, or you could simply write a Python script that would iterate over the tags in the document and throw an error if it finds one that is wrong.